# Is 0xF8 a valid byte in a UTF-8 encoded XML document?

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8

I am receiving a document that claims to be UTF-8 (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`). I've had some problems in the past where the encoding declaration from the sender has not been all that reliable (i.e. documents are declared to have a given encoding when in fact they do not), so I try to check using http://utf8checker.codeplex.com/ According to this tool, a 0xF8 byte means that this document is not UTF-8 encoded.

However, to the contrary, [this page](http://folk.uio.no/dflaguti/Side1.html) lists the Norwegian character 'ø' as being represented in UTF-8 as 0xF8. (The page is in Norwegian, however, the data I am referring to stems from the table at the bottom of the page.)

Can anyone help me sort this out? I'm feeling rather confused here.

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably 8859-1 or Latin-1.

Comment: @9000: ISO 8859-1 *is* Latin-1. Those are simply two different names for the exact same character set and encoding.

Comment: Yes, I should have said ISO8859-1 aka Latin-1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ø is U+00F8 and since it is not in ASCII it cannot be a single UTF-8 code unit. It is represented by [0xC3 0xB8 in UTF-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f8/index.htm). Therefore, if you have 0xF8 standing alone in a document somewhere, yes, it is invalid UTF-8.

It seems that the document uses either Latin-1 or the Windows code page 1252.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that page is very reliable, it also says "UTF-8 = UCS-1".

Checking [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), F8 can only be used as the first byte of a 5 byte UTF-8 sequence, but currently no Unicode characters exist which would require 5 byte encoding. So no.

Comment: And the norwegian page says that UTF-16 is a fixed-length encoding, which is also wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The utf8checker tool is right and the page you are referring to is wrong. The UTF-8 representation of 'ø' is 0xC3 0xB8 (two bytes).

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f8/index.htm